# How to keep remote database connection password updated regularly for Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, winforms

I am building a Windows Form Application for a website. The application fetches data from the remote database server of the website and stores in local database at client side. What I want is that when I change the database connection password at the server side, the application should update that password in its settings file for the next time when it connects to remote database server.

What I tried to achieve this is that, when application starts, it downloads a file with encrypted password from the server and then updates its settings file with that password.

But I was wondering if any other optimized and more secure way available.

Comment: For clarification, are you connecting to a SQL database directly across the Internet?

Comment: yes, I am using sql lite at local n sql server 2008 at remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do looks ok though as you don't have much option out there.

However I can suggest one thing out of box i.e. Web Services.

Web Services with SSL would also be a charm.

I am not sure if it will make much sense or  not.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downloading file and retrieve the encrypted password, You can create a webmethod which is return the encrypted password string.

Create a new column in any config table for maintaining Server's Password. Whenever you want to change the Server's password. Please update the column value.

Create a simple web service with single web method to fetch the encrypted Server's password.

In Windows App, Invoke the web method while loading the application. Get the password and build dynamic connection string to connect the client.

Else.

Use web service to retrieve the data from centralized sever, It's more secure and reliable.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

if you store database password in plain old settings file of .net, you cant talk about security. and no, there is no standardized or optimized approach for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to keep database server hidden from the client. You can implement simple client server architecture.
But, anyways, if you have implemented it this way, then yes. The way you doing is the fine. You can directly get the password as object. No need of using a file.